# How can I check what types of parameters a given function expects?

Tags: python, types, parameters

I currently have a function which I think should take an int, however that produces an error. Now I want to find out what the function actually expects. The only ways of doing this that I know of are:

1. Check the documentation.
2. If that fails: try to figure it out from the source code.
3. If that fails: guess until something works.

Is there another way of figuring out what the function expects as input?

context: I am working with theano and want to input a 0 in a model. However a 0 could be an int, a numpy.array, a theano.tensor, a theano.scalar or some other object. I am trying to figure out what exactly is needed here. The issue is that I am having trouble getting the answer from the documentation and source code and am a bit frustrated that I can't seem to just 'ask' the function what it wants. I am getting a np-complete vibe from this: easy to check whether a given input-type is correct, hard to find from scratch what works.

Comment: You could try the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module. Python doesn't check types, it just assumes. But it might give you a slightly better idea on what the function does, use after step 2.

Comment: Python often employs duck typing, so may accept arguments of a variety of types. If those aren't properly documented (bad developer, no treat!), then yes, those other two options are usually your only real approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I guess as far as programming languages goes: with great flexibility comes great responsibility.